# php htmlspecialchars() from one form to another

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

Why can't htmlspecialchars() continually encode characters after each form submission?  Take a look at the following example:

```
<?php $_POST['txt'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['txt']); ?>
<form method="post">
<input name="txt" value="<?=$_POST['txt'] ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="save" value="test" />
</form>
```

You can see it at running at http://verticalcms.com/htmlspecialchars.php.

Now do the following

```
1) Type & into the text field
2) Hit the test button once
3) When the page completes post back, hit the test button again
4) When the page completes post back, view the page source code
```

In the input box, the value is & amp;

I was expecting & amp; amp;

Why is it not & amp; amp;  ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simply is HTML entity encoding. When using "&" in an HTML attribute, it should be encoded. And this is what you are doing.

So, the browser reads

```
<input value="&amp;" />
```

and translates it to an "textbox widget with value '&'".

The same would be true for other special chars:

```
<input value="&quot" />
```

would result in a " character.

When you submit the form, the browser sends these values unencoded, therefore your PHP script receives it like "&", not "&amp;".

Comment: So when the user hits the & on his keyboard, the browser automatically encodes it into & amp; before inserting it into <input value="& amp;"/> ?

Comment: No. &amp; is only required for escaping & in HTML. Once the page is parsed and rendered, the browser doesn't care about the HTML any more. The value of the generated texbox widget is '&' when the user hits '&'. When submitting the form, the data is sent via HTTP -- no more HTML is involved.

Comment: ah i see, that makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: This is a bit late, but actually, the browser changes it from &amp; to &, then again from & to %26, as & is a special character in GET/POST... PHP then decodes %26 back to & on the receiving side.

Comment: And this is also not true when using POST with "multipart/form-data" encoding :)

Answer (score 0):

The values in $_POST are already html-decoded for convenience. So when your script starts, the following is true:

```
$_POST['txt'] == '&';
htmlspecialchars('&') == '&amp;'
```

[edit]
Looks like this needs further explanation

When a form like the one above is submitted to the server by the browser with a single ampersand as the value of 'txt', it puts the following into the body of the request:

```
txt=&amp;
```

The value is encoded because the browser would concatenate multiple fields with an ampersand character like

```
txt=&amp;&user=soulmerge&pass=whatever
```

PHP takes the transmitted values and decodes them for the convenience of the programmer - it makes an ampersand out of & Now I though this was the reason for the question in the first place - guess I got it wrong. The actual question was answered correctly by Ferdinand.

Comment: "The values in $_POST are already html-decoded for convenience" -- Sorry, but this is not true. When you send HTML-encoded data via GET or POST, they will be available "as is" in your script, no automatical decoding is done.